# How do you access a dictionary object within a list without using indices?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to create a directory of folders and files for each user, and I can't seem to access a dictionary for a folder within a list of all of a user's files **but only using the folder name, not by indexing**.

I could iterate over the list and check if the element is a dictionary with the folder name I'm trying to access, but I felt like there was probably an easier way.

```
userDir = {"User1": [{"folder1": [file1, file2]}, file3], "User2": []}
```

What's the best way I could access the dictionary key "folder1" here?

`for obj in userDir["User1"]:
    if type(obj) == dict:
        if "folder1" in obj.keys():
            print(obj["folder1"])  # Or do something else with "folder1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as you've noted is that `userDir["User1"]` is a list. There's really no way to find a thing in a list, without iterating through that list and actually looking at each thing (apart from using indexes ofc).

Python does provide a few nice ways of searching through lists, for example, list comprehensions:

```
user1 = [x for x in userDir["User1"] if isinstance(x, dict) and "folder1" in x.keys()]
```

However the real answer is that the data format is not appropriate for what you're trying to do. It'd be far cleaner to make your `userDir` look more like:

```
userDir = {
    "User1": {
        "folder1": [file1, file2, file3]
    },
    "User2": {}
}
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: The thing is that you'd probably want to get rid of that nested list as well. One folder can contain another after all, and it would be nice to access files by name too. If your folder contents is a dict, files can have None or some useful marker object as the value.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you'd better not to use list for your folders, because you should use index or iterate items to seek any file in your data structure, anyway.

Without list type, your directory will be like

```
userDir = {
    "User1": {
        "folder1": {
            "file1": file1,
            "file2": file2
        },
        "file3": file3
    },
    "User2": {
    }
}
```

And if this is because order of files matters, you have several options.

1. Use list and iterate
2. order only by file(folder)name
3. Set meta info (including order) to each item and order every time you fetch
4. Have order info in each folder

If you can take Option 2 it is most simple and easy to handle, I think.

Otherwise:

3. Set meta info (including order) to each item and order every time you fetch

(probably you should use classes instead of dict)

```
userDir = {
    "_type": "folder",
    "User1": {
        "_type": "folder",
        "folder1": {
            "_type": "folder",
            "file1": {
                "_type": "file",
                "_content": file1,
                "_order": 1,
            },
            "file2": {
                "_type": "file",
                "_content": file2,
                "_order": 2,
            },
        },
        "file3": {
            "_type": "file",
            "_content": file3,
            "_order": 1,
        },
    },
    "User2": {
        "_type": "folder",
    }
}
```

4. Have order info in each folder

```
userDir = {
    "_order": ["User1", "User2"],
    "User1": {
        "_order": ["folder1", "file3"],
        "folder1": {
            "_order": ["User1", "User2"],
            "file1": file1,
            "file2": file2
        },
        "file3": file3
    },
    "User2": {
    }
}
```